# inline assembly with microsoft cl tool

Tags: inline-assembly, command-line-tool

How can I build inline assembly with the Microsoft cl tool? when I try the standard

```
 asm(nop);
```

it says unresolved external symbol asm. Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
__asm
{
    nop
    mov   eax, 4
}
```